# Full screen terminal with script as screen saver under archLinux

Tags: arch-linux, scripting, screensaver

Bonjour, Is it possible to run a terminal at full screen running a script instead of the screen saver ? That means that after 10 minutes of inactivity the screen should go black and show the STDOUT of a script (ex cmatrix or fortune), and then go away when clicking with the mouse / with a keystroke.
I'm running Antergos (ArchLinux) with the last version of Gnome.
If you have any ideas on how I could do this, I would really appreciate.

Comment: One idea: you could use `tmux`, set automatic locking, and give it a custom lock command.

Comment: Thanks, but wouldn't that work only in console only mode ? I'm running Gnome... I could have used xscreensaver, but I think to achieve that I would have to emulate a terminal in a screensaver module which would be really complicated. So maybe there is something simpler, a soft that does that or just a way to launch a terminal on top of everything that disappear on mouse move ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is cmatrix. you can use this command to run cmatrix in a fullscreen gnome-terminal:

```
gnome-terminal --window --full-screen -- /bin/sh -c 'sleep 0.1s; cmatrix
```

you can assign a keyboard shortcut for this command. For example <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>
as you press <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> a fullscreen terminal starts running cmatrix, and if you press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> it goes away.

Comment: It's 2020, and lots of things has been changed. I found that the above command does not work any more. you can use below command:
`gnome-terminal --window --full-screen -- /bin/sh -c 'sleep 0.1s; cmatrix'`

Answer (score 0):

I've used a fullscreen xterm running a script to disable it when a key is pressed. But it's a screen saver taking all of my CPU. Not really optimized x)