# How can I activate/configure a screensaver in Wayland/GNOME?

Tags: gnome, wayland, screensaver, xscreensaver

I am using Fedora 25 with Wayland and GNOME. How can I configure a screensaver?

I assume `xscreensaver` does not work and I could install `gnome-screensaver`, but there is no configuration interface - or have I missed something there…?

**Edit**: To clarify, I am not looking for a simple black screen or a "fade out" effect, but for a "real" screensaver showing some animation or a slideshow of your photos/images or so…

---

Question cross-posted from [Ask Fedora](https://ask.fedoraproject.org/en/question/106077/how-can-i-activateconfigure-a-screensaver-in-waylandgnome/).

Comment: Did You ever find a solution to this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So basically I could not find any real wayland-screensaver solution. There was [some development](https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=MTAxODY) and even a [small demo](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=y37WPw-6HTM) of a Wayland screensaver (wscreensaver), but there is not a final program or maybe not even the inital implementation made it into Wayland.

In any case I did not expect that I can (of course) run X.org apps under Wayland using XWayland. Naturally this may not last long into the future, but currently it works. I can run `xscreensaver` as it is expected.

Answer (score 1):

From the Gnome GUI desktop, try going to `Settings` -> `Privacy` -> `Screen Lock`

Comment: I should clarify my question: I am not looking for a simple black screen or some "fade out" effect, which you describe here and which is actually the default way, but for a "real" screensaver showing some animation or a slideshow of your photos/images or so…

Answer (score 0):

You could try i3lock, i3lock-blur or i3lock-fancy , it's really tweakable, you can have it to blur your desktop or show an image, you can script it however you like to change the background and it shows by default date and time.

I don't know how to launch a screen saver on Wayland, but It could just be done with a script reading libinput-debug-events, launching the screensaver when there is no events for 15 minutes for instance.

You could also use a full screen terminal / full screen feh to display an animation or an image as explained here : [Full screen terminal with script as screen saver under archLinux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/255766/full-screen-terminal-with-script-as-screen-saver-under-archlinux)

Comment: i3lock seems to be more about locking and showing some static image (e.g. a white screen in the default config) than a "real screensaver" with some kind of animation.